# How to edit and test a verilog netlist

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, netlist

I've used a design compiler to produce a netlist for a simple serial adder.

I want to add a watermark to the design, which requires me to add a few gates and flip flops to the design.

How can I test the code after making edits (I'm not sure how to compile gate-level code, usually use ModelSim) to make sure it works, and how do I compile the new netlist.

P.S I am a noob, sry, any links to fundemental tutorials and stuff can help, thx :)

Comment: The output is verilog. You could simply compile it in Modelsim, just like you would with behavioral-style Verilog RTL that you'd have synthesized to create this netlist.

Comment: @ArunD'souza You would need the library models for the components too.

Comment: @oldfart I used the 0.35 um AMS technology library, do you have any pointers how to simulate using this? If I try use modelsim to run a normal testbench I get a bunch of "Module '___' is not defined" errors.

Comment: You need an simulation library from AMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile and simulate a netlist just like any other verilog design files. You will need to include the library files for the technology you synthesized for as part of your compilation filelist

Answer (score 0):

Though the "coding styles" really differ bewteen your RTL .v and the gate-level netlist .v, there're no essential differences between them. A hierarchical HDL design is a design with nested modules. After synthesis, the *AND* gate inferred from `&` in your RTL becomes a newly created sub-module. Without the .v that defines such gate cells, your simulation tool doesn't know what functionality the *AND* gate has, and will report "Module '*AND*' is not defined" errors. Such files are called standard library simulation models, and are mainly located inside `frontend` part of your library path. Try searching for "*.v" or "*.src", and incude them in your file list.